# Bundler binstub has infinite loop

Tags: ruby, bundler

- I have an app with an executable called `little_bird`.
- I use rbenv, Ruby 2.0.0-p195, and Bundler 1.3.5.
- The `little_bird` executable works fine when I call it with `bundle exec`.
- I don't want to use `bundle exec`, so I ran `bundle install --binstubs`.
- This replaced the content of my bin directory with a bunch of binstubs, as I'd expect.
- However, trying to run the `little_bird` binstub causes Bundler to barf out a huge error log.

Investigation reveals that the line

```
load Gem.bin_path('little_bird-cli', 'little_bird')
```

which is the very last line in the binstub, is creating an infinite loop; i.e.

```
Gem.bin_path('little_bird-cli', 'little_bird')
```

just points right back at the binstub!

Where does Bundler put my actual executable and how can I fix this problem?